# How to return a List(Of String) from a LINQ statement with a Group By in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, linq

I've seen several questions on how to do this in C# but I'm having trouble translating those to VB. Here's the basics of my issue:

- Table of data NOT normalized and accessed via Entity Framework
- Get all unique string values in a certain field
- Convert those values to a `List(Of String)`

This works but I'm guessing there's a better way to do it without iterating through the list:

```
Public Function GetGroups() As IEnumerable(Of String)
    Dim GroupList As New List(Of String)

    Dim CodeList = (From c In Context.Codes
                    Group c.Group By c.Group Into g = Group)

    For Each c In CodeList
        GroupList.Add(c.Group)
    Next

    Return GroupList
End Function
```

What I seem to be struggling with the most is using Group By in LINQ. I'm guessing this could probably be done in 1 or 2 lines by having LINQ return just the list of strings or by converting the list of anonymous objects to a list of strings.

Comment: The code is confusing me, but your description sounds like you want `Return From c In Context.Codes Select c.Group Distinct`, where "Group" is the property you want the unique values from?

Comment: Sounds like what you are really looking for is `Distinct` rather than `Group By`, since you aren't doing any type of aggregation, summation, etc.

Comment: If you haven't used LinqPad, I highly recommend it.  It helped me understand how Group works in Linq.  It's quite different than T-SQL if that's what you're used to.

Comment: @pseudocoder Installing LinqPad now per your suggestion.

Comment: @Mark Frankly, it confused me as well but that's where I ended up after a bunch of searching and fiddling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you don't need anything in the group, you can just use `.Distinct()`:

```
Return (
    From c In Context.Codes
    Order By c.Group
    Select c.Group
).Distinct().ToList()
```

Edit: Added Order By

Comment: Correct.  And even if you wrote it as a `Group By`, it would be optimized into a `Select Distinct`.

Comment: The only issue I ran into was that I lost the order. Group By in my code must be doing an OrderBy. I needed to add the OrderBy like so:     .Distinct.OrderBy(Function(g) g).ToList.